# Any method to bypass login page in share point site using username and password or token to getting share point site

Tags: sharepoint

Any method to bypass login page in share point site using username and password or token  to getting  share point site using java.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend the [PLGSharepointRestAPI-java](https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java) to you.

You can use following code to connect sharepoint

```
// Initialize the API
PLGSharepointClient wrapper = new PLGSharepointClient(user, passwd, domain, spSiteUrl);
try {
    JSONObject result = wrapper.getAllLists("{}");
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```